# Getting duplicates after added lines on join

Tags: sql, duplicates

After adding just a few more joins I get duplicates and other data when I do the join.  Any ideas what I possibly could be doing wrong?

Old code that worked with no dupes:

```
SELECT
    dbo.dateonly(ctl.datetrans) AS DateRecorded, 
    L.Clientkey AS ClientNum, 
    L.Fullname, 
    cs.Datesvc, 
    cs.chargekey, 
    ctl.CheckNum, 
    ctl.ReceivedFrom, 
    ctl.Delta, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), dept.deptkey) AS Deptkey, 
    dept.DeptName, 
    dept.PgmName, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), dept.pgmKey) AS PGMKey, 
    ctl.Transtypelu
FROM
    bil_Chargetranslog ctl 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.BIL_ChargeSlips cs 
        ON cs.Chargekey = ctl.Chargekey 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.BLV_Clients L 
        ON cs.ClientKey = L.ClientKey 
    LEFT JOIN Blv_DeptPgm dept 
        ON dept.Pgmkey = cs.PgmLU
WHERE
    (
        ctl.Transtypelu = 4 
        AND (
            (
                ctl.descr <> 'Client Payment' 
                AND ctl.descr <> 'Copayment'
            ) OR ctl.descr IS NULL
        )
    )

UNION ALL

/* note below that the checknum is converted to a varchar for the query*/ 
SELECT 
    dbo.dateonly(daterecorded) AS daterecorded, 
    L.Clientkey AS ClientNum, 
    L.Fullname, 
    DatePayment, 
    NULL AS chargekey, 
    CONVERT(varchar(15), checknum) AS checknum, 
    NULL AS receivedfrom, 
    (- 1 * Amount) AS delta, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), dept.deptkey) AS Deptkey, 
    dept.DeptName, 
    dept.PgmName, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), dept.pgmKey) AS PGMKey, 
    4 AS transtypelu
FROM
    bil_clientdeposit 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.BLV_Clients L 
        ON bil_clientdeposit.ClientKey = L.ClientKey 
    LEFT JOIN Blv_DeptPgm dept 
        ON dept.Pgmkey = Bil_ClientDeposit.PgmKey
```

This is my new code:

```
SELECT
    dbo.dateonly(ctl.datetrans) AS DateRecorded, 
    L.Clientkey AS ClientNum, 
    L.Fullname, 
    cs.Datesvc, 
    cs.chargekey, 
    ctl.CheckNum, 
    ctl.ReceivedFrom, 
    ctl.Delta, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), dept.deptkey) AS Deptkey, 
    dept.DeptName, 
    dept.PgmName, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), dept.pgmKey) AS PGMKey, 
    ctl.Transtypelu, 
    pr.PlanName
FROM
    bil_Chargetranslog ctl 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.BIL_ChargeSlips cs 
        ON cs.Chargekey = ctl.Chargekey 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.BLV_Clients L 
        ON cs.ClientKey = L.ClientKey 
    LEFT JOIN Blv_DeptPgm dept 
        ON dept.Pgmkey = cs.PgmLU 
    left join BIL_ARTRANSLOG AR 
        ON ctl.chargekey = ar.chargekey 
    left join BIL_PAYORPLANS PR 
        ON PR.PAYORPLANKEY = AR.PAYORPLANKEY
WHERE
    (
        ctl.Transtypelu = 4 
        and ar.TransTypeLU = 4 
        AND (
            (
                ctl.descr <> 'Client Payment' 
                and AR.ARDescr <> 'Client Payment' 
                AND ctl.descr <> 'Copayment'
                and AR.ARDescr <> 'Copayment'
            ) OR ctl.descr IS NULL 
            or ar.ARDescr is null
        )
    )

UNION ALL

/* note below that the checknum is converted to a varchar for the query*/ 
SELECT  
    dbo.dateonly(daterecorded) AS daterecorded, 
    L.Clientkey AS ClientNum, 
    L.Fullname, 
    DatePayment, 
    NULL AS chargekey, 
    CONVERT(varchar(15), checknum) AS checknum, 
    NULL AS receivedfrom, 
    (- 1 * Amount) AS delta, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), dept.deptkey) AS Deptkey, 
    dept.DeptName, 
    dept.PgmName, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), dept.pgmKey) AS PGMKey, 
    4 AS transtypelu, 
    NULL as planname
FROM
    bil_clientdeposit 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.BLV_Clients L 
        ON bil_clientdeposit.ClientKey = L.ClientKey 
    LEFT JOIN Blv_DeptPgm dept 
        ON dept.Pgmkey = Bil_ClientDeposit.PgmKey
```

I added the lines:

```
left join BIL_ARTRANSLOG AR 
    ON ctl.chargekey = ar.chargekey 
left join BIL_PAYORPLANS PR 
    ON PR.PAYORPLANKEY = AR.PAYORPLANKEY
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between "union" and "union all" is that the latter returns all records while the former returns distinct records.  If you don't want duplicate records, use the former.

Comment: nothing on that, I think its a problem with some rows have extra data sometimes and others not.  Ill check this out with only a SELECT statment.

Comment: If that's the case, they are not duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you added a couple extra joins and suddenly are seeing duplicate rows, there is probably a one-to-many relationship in one or both of the joined tables that does not exist in the other joined tables.  Try doing a `SELECT *` and see what the differing columns are on what appears to be duplicate records.

You can remove the duplicates by preceding your `SELECT` statements with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dbo.dateonly(ctl.datetrans) AS DateRecorded, 
    L.Clientkey AS ClientNum, 
    L.Fullname, 
    ....
```

Comment: Good idea, ill see what select gets me first.